# Why is iCal.Net generating an invalid time?

Tags: c#, icalendar

I'm generating a .ics document using iCal.Net.

```
Event calendarEvent = new Event
{
    IsAllDay = false,
    Summary = "summary",
    Description = "summary",
    DtStart = new CalDateTime(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(start,TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time")), "America/New_York"),
    DtEnd = new CalDateTime(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(end, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time")), "America/New_York")
};

var calendar = new Calendar();
calendar.AddTimeZone(new VTimeZone("America/New_York"));
calendar.Events.Add(calendarEvent);

var serializer = new CalendarSerializer(new SerializationContext());
return serializer.SerializeToString(calendar);
```

Usually, the resulting start and end date look similar to this:

```
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20170106T132000
DTSTAMP:20170104T005548Z
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20170106T130000
```

However, they are occasionally generated like this:

```
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20180105T002000
DTSTAMP:20170105T191635Z
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York;VALUE=DATE:20180105
```

In particular, notice the `VALUE=DATE:20180105` next to `DTSTART`. For whatever reason, this causes most calendar applications to read the event as an all day event (even though, as you can see above, I explicitly say it isn't).

What's going on?

EDIT:

The start dates are June 1, 2017, 1PM for the first example, and May 1, 2018, 12AM for the second. I think it has something to do with the fact that in the second datetime, the time is the default value

Comment: Well, what is the value of `start` in those cases?

Comment: Sorry, added that info to the problem statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently since `date + 12AM` is 0 ticks after `date`, iCal.net assumes that you are referring to `date` (without the time) when you create an instance of `CalDateTime`.

If you look at the object properties on `new CalDateTime(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(start,TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time")), "America/New_York")` where `start` is at 12AM, you can see that `HasTime` is `false`.

Fortunately, this property is `get; set;`. So simply set it to `true`, and the problem vanishes.